# Facing code EWORKSPACESCONFIG issue while npm install

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-install

Below error, I am getting while doing npm install for react-native.

```
npm ERR! code EWORKSPACESCONFIG
npm ERR! workspaces config expects an Array
```

Answer (score 3):

Didnt work for me too so I used yarn instead of npm and that worked

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of this error is npm version. I tried many things but none of them worked.

Try to **upgrade** or **downgrade** npm version. Will fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I erased the workspaces entry and used npm i --force @tailwindcss/typography  and it seemed to solve it.