# npx serve -s build error: EWORKSPACESCONFIG workspaces config expects an Array

Tags: reactjs, build, web-deployment

I tried to build my reactJS web using command `npx serve -s build` and what I get is an error:

```
npm ERR! code EWORKSPACESCONFIG
npm ERR! workspaces config expects an Array

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Tomato\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-24T11_05_57_206Z-debug-0.log
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you post the log? What node version do you use? Do you try to clean build dir? and node_modules?

Answer (score 1):

Your build is failing using **npx serve -s build** because of having workspaces property as an object in the **package.json** file instead of an array.

Although, an object is a valid type for workspaces property as per Yarn documentation.

For more information on bug please click [here](https://issuehunt.io/r/storybookjs/storybook/issues/15765)

Try to build your project using `yarn build` **OR** try to change the object of workspace to array. Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65580429/facing-code-eworkspacesconfig-issue-while-npm-install) answer your question?

If not please provide additional information